# Do you know of tubes that are fully flat-proof?

Tags: innertube

I am looking into whether there are inner tubes that are fully flat proof.  Do you know how much they would affect performance and comfort?

Comment: If you are asking because you are constantly getting flats: There are (almost) puncture proof tires like the Schwalbe Marathon Plus or Continental Touring Plus which should be strong enough even for cities with glass shards everywhere. And they behave much better than airless tires/tubes.

Comment: I wonder how a marathon plus combined with a tyre liner *and* a thick tube compares to a solid tyre for weight. I'm sure the timing resistance would be better. Perhaps this might be a solution for someone paranoid about punctures (though the tyres @Michael suggests are enough for me and most people).

Comment: 25 years ago I rode to high school on a 10 speed with "No More Flats" tubes.  They were sealed and did not have a valve stem. Incredibly bumpy ride, because they were always rock hard.  I rode on them for years until the tube perished and split.  On inspection, the walls of the tube were about 1/3 the diameter, with only a thin empty space in the middle.  They haven't been available here for decades, but my Dad remembers they were easily a dozen times the price of regular tubes.  Just use puncture-resistant tubes.

Comment: What kind of flats are you getting? Short of using a solid tube, no tube is going to help if you're getting pinch flats due to inadequate tire pressure.

Comment: Since nobody's brought it up yet, if you are constantly getting flats: *something is wrong*. This is not normal, and many people go many thousands of miles in-between punctures. Use an appropriate tire for the type of riding you do (MTB, cross, commuting, etc), an appropriate sized tire for your weight, and *keep them properly inflated*.

Comment: Second @StephenTouset.  I commute daily and get maybe one flat a year.  I don't even carry a kit on my single speed.   A solid tube would be a significant negative impact on performance and comfort.   They are not popular for a reason.

Comment: Thank you all for very informative insights on the issue.  No, I don't get flat tire often.  I am just totally helpless at replacing them.  A few years back, I had a kit got a flat.  Worked for 20 minutes at replacing a flat, got a bunch of my fingers all bloodied up and did not achieve anything.  I ended up hitchiking my way home.  Now, when I get flats I typically stand ready to get to the nearest bike shop.  Where I bike I typically can get to one within a couple of miles.  If not, I'd hitchhike again.  Pathetic but true.  Otherwise, believe it or not I am a pretty good biker.

Comment: There are several different variations on solid rubber tires/tubes.  But I've found that simply getting some sort of puncture-resistant tire (I'm fond of the Kevlar-belted ones) can reduce punctures by a factor of at least 10, maybe 50.

Comment: (And don't attempt to patch a tube on the road, except as a last resort.  Carry a spare tube.)

Comment: @GaetanLion: Learn to change tires/tubes. It’s really no rocket science, you just need two or three tire leavers of good quality and apply them tactically. Road bikes with folding tires are the worst, everything else is usually fairly easy.

Comment: @ChrisH I'm not convinced by tire liners. I tried them together with puncture-proof Schwalbe tires for a year, but got a couple of punctures because they pinched the tube. Took them out and no more punctures since then. Although I'm normally fairly adapt at bike repairs and despite following all instructions and youtube videos I could find, I don't think I managed to keep them aligned properly, at least not with wide tires (might be easier with thin tires and higher pressure). They probably moved at lower pressure.

Comment: @Stephan I use some on my second bike because I already had tyres and was spending as little as possible. This bike runs 26x1.95 tyres and this was near the middle of the width range on the liners. Getting them right on anything much narrower would be tricky. So far so good but I've only done a couple of hundred miles on them on poor tarmac (and I don't check the pressure as often as I should because the bike is usually in another city).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they're usually solid rubber and they're very heavy, hard to fit and have a lot more rolling resistance than you're used to. Companies like ["airless tyres"](http://www.airlesstiresnow.com/Flat-Proof-Inner-Tubes_c_62.html) make them, and I suggest trying to fit them yourself before taking them to a bike shop and paying whatever they ask to have them fit the solid tubes.

You can also get puncture resistant tubes that have thicker walls than normal tubes, and while they are heavier than normal tubes they're nothing like solid tubes. They also don't work very well. You're better off with puncture resistant tyres.

Finally, you can get sealants that you pump into the tube that will leak a little then seal, like [Slime](http://slime.com/212/products/16-oz-tube-sealant-for-bike-dirt-bike-and-wheelbarrow-10004/). Tubeless tyres use a similar sealant, but swapping to tubeless is a major change and there are many sites [describing that process](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=convert%20to%20tubeless%20bicycle)

Comment: I remember seeing a company sometime back that was making airless systems with varying types of foam to simulate different tire pressures.  The idea was that they were still heavier, but you could choose whether your solid tyre felt like it had 150psi or 35psi in it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that basics are in order and that you are using properly sized tires and inflating them to proper pressure, typical route to get more puncture resiliency is to use different tires with better puncture protection, not different tubes. It reduced my puncture frequency dramatically, I expect it would also help you.

Answer (score 1):

They are also solid one-piece tires made by Tannus (http://www.tannus.com/#tires) and AmeriTyre ( http://www.amerityre.com/our-flat-free-products/bicycle-tires) that will replace the whole tire and inner tube. One thing to consider with these kinda of tires is that the depth of the rim must be meassured properly otherwise the tires will roll-off the rim if it's too loose. They also have a higher rolling resistance and will take some getting used a "smushy" feeling while riding.

Acme Tires (http://www.acmebikeparts.com/) offer flat-free tires and wheel-sets packages if you don't want to do it yourself or take it to an LBS. These are on the expensive side.